# Automate Mail merge in Excel VBA - Not sending multiple emails

Tags: html, vba, excel, html-email

This is an automated mail merge that I pieced together from a few different sites.

It's been altered many times to make sure the email that sends is HTML and includes the default users signature.

After button click, a window pops up to select a range, the email is then personalised depending on the range selection.

```
           Sub EmailAttachmentRecipients()
'updateby Extendoffice 20160506
Dim xOutlook As Object
Dim xMailItem As Object
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCell As Range
Dim xTxt As String
Dim Signature As String
Dim xEmail As String
Dim xSubj As String
Dim xMsg As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Double


' Create window to select range
  xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.address
  Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the arresses list:", "Water Corporation Mail Merge", xTxt, , , , , 8)
  If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub



  For i = 1 To xRg.rows.Count

  Set xOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set xMailItem = xOutlook.CreateItem(0)

xMsg = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Verdana>" & Sheet2.Cells(4, 2) & " " & xRg.Cells(i, 1) & ",</BODY>" & "<br>"
xMsg = xMsg & "" & Sheet2.Cells(6, 2) & " " & Sheet2.Cells(6, 4) & " " & Sheet2.Cells(6, 6) & " " & "<br>" & "<br>"
xMsg = xMsg & "" & Sheet2.Cells(8, 2) & " " & "<br>" & "<br>"
xMsg = xMsg & "" & Sheet2.Cells(10, 2) & "" & "<br>"

 xEmail = xRg.Cells(i, 2)

 With xMailItem
    .Display
    .To = xEmail
    .CC = ""
    .Subject = "" & Sheet2.Cells(2, 2) & " " & xRg.Cells(i, 3) & " - " & xRg.Cells(i, 4) & ""
    .HTMLBody = xMsg & .HTMLBody
    .Send
   End With

 Set xOutlook = Nothing
 Set xMailItem = Nothing
 Next i
End Sub
```

I'm having trouble getting the code to send more than one email, as in select a range of 5 rows and the email client only sends off one email.

Does anyone have any direction they could lend?

Thanks everyone for solving this!

Comment: why is there nothing inside your for loop?

Comment: Sorry Guys, just re-edited as per the above code in the question after Sven Ras's answer, seems to be working much better now however now when I send to multiple each following email includes the info from the last email. As in email 1 says hello Sven. email 2 says Hello Sven, Hello John. Email 3 days Hello Sven, Hello John, Hello Peter.

Comment: add set xoutlook =nothing set xmailitem=nothing at the end of the loop

Comment: or you can create the outlook object outside the loop and set it to nothing at the end after the loop.

Comment: Thanks Sivar, I tried that as per the above? Doesn't seem to be working though, is it included correctly?

Comment: thing is you are creating this in xmsg and concatenating every time loop is executed....if you dont want that. you can just use xmsg=your values.....instead of xmsg =xmsg& your values.....for the first xmsg trying using only your values and not concatenating.....else try setting xmsg to nothing at the end of loop

Comment: Perfect thank you Siva! Works perfectly now, just like you said; removing the first xMsg & which was concatenating every loop!

Comment: Do not edit your question to remove the problem. The whole point is to keep the problem visible, so people can see your question, realize they have the same issue, and get help from the answers. If you fix the code in your question, there's no point in having it anymore. Please undo that change.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as though you aren't putting the compose email in the loop.

```
For i = 1 To xRg.rows.Count
<<put email composing code here>>
Next I
```

Comment: shouldnt the I variable increments and comes out of the loop before entering the email composing code. So the .to method has a values of row out of the range. Doesnt that give an error Subscript out of range, rather than sending the mail once?